# Using R to simulate multiple days

Tags: r, simulation

Using this function which simulates the number of guests arriving at a resturant over an 8 hour period where lambda = 10 customers per hour, guests = maximum number of guests (=12) that can be served and hours = restaurant open 8 hours a day. How would I go about simulating 5000 days at the restaurant?

```
set.seed(0)
waiting_guests <- function(lambda, guests, hours) {
  #null vector vec
  vec <- c()
  # initialize values as in the code
  current_guests <- 0
  remaining_guests <- 0
  #while loop with condition hours != 0
  while (hours != 0) {
    # update values
    current_guests <- remaining_guests+rpois (1, lambda)
    remaining_guests <- max( current_guests - guests, 0)
    vec <-c(vec, remaining_guests)
    #update hours
    hours <-hours-1;
  }
  # return the vector
  return (vec)
}

answer <- waiting_guests(10,12,8)
  
print(answer)
```

```
[1] 1 0 2 4 3 5 5 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this achieve what you're looking for:

```
sims <- vector("list", length = 5000)
sims <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:5000, function(.) waiting_guests(lambda = 10, guests = 12, hours = 8)))
```

You didn't specify what you want your output to be stored in so in this instance it will be stored in a dataframe.  You can also do the following to store each `sims` vector in a list of vectors.

```
sims <- vector("list", length = 5000)
sims <- lapply(1:5000, function(.) waiting_guests(lambda = 10, guests = 12, hours = 8))
```

Another way is to use a for loop but I don't think it's necessary since the `lapply` function should be faster and it's only a two-liner:

```
day <- 1
days <- 1:5000
answers <- vector("list", length = 5000)
for (day in seq_along(days)) {
  answers[[day]] <- waiting_guests(10,12,8)
}
answers <- do.call(rbind, answers)
```

Comment: Also what would be the most appropriate ggplot graph to display the distribution of guests waiting at the end of each hour?

Comment: @DaveJohnson123 you should post a new question for the graphing part. The first thing that comes to mind is a bar plot, something like `geom_bar` in ggplot. Using the results from my code, you could use the results in the dataframe  to plot the distribution of each variable (or column) with `geom_bar`. Also, if the answer(s) provided achieve what you were trying to code you should accept the answer or clarify what else is needed.